# Non-dimensionalizing the Ideal MHD System

Tags: computational-physics, nonlinear-equations, parallel-computing

Non-dimensionalization is a really frustrating topic for me, and I imagine many others, because in school it was glossed over while being really important to implementing a simulation.

I'm writing a CUDA C/C++ project on a single GPU in order to solve the Ideal MHD equations, but have run into a barrier where I need to non-dimensionalize the system, but I'm not sure how to do this.

For expressions like $\frac{B^{2}}{2\mu_{0}}$, it's clear that $\tilde{B} = \frac{B}{\sqrt{\mu_{0}}}$ works, but for more complicated expressions like the energy $e = \frac{p}{\gamma - 1} + \frac{\rho v^{2}}{2} + \frac{B^{2}}{2\mu_{0}}$, I am lost. What do I do? What is the procedure?

For reference, here is the full Ideal MHD system, in conservative form, with a numerical diffusion, that I am solving:

$$\frac{\partial\vec{Q}}{\partial t} + \vec{\nabla}\cdot\overleftrightarrow{T} = D\nabla^{2}\vec{Q}$$

The Ideal MHD variables, $\vec{Q}$, are:

$$ \vec{Q} = \pmatrix{\rho \\ \rho u \\ \rho v \\ \rho w \\ B_{x} \\ B_{y} \\ B_{z} \\ e} $$

where $e$ was previously expressed. The fluxes, $\overleftrightarrow{T} = [\vec{F} \quad \vec{G} \quad \vec{H}]^{T} $, are broken down into the following components,

$$
\vec{F} = 
\pmatrix{
\rho u \\ 
\rho u^{2} - \frac{B_{x}^{2}}{\mu_{0}} + p + \frac{B^{2}}{2\mu_{0}} \\ \rho v u - \frac{B_{y}B_{x}}{\mu_{0}} \\
\rho w u - \frac{B_{z}B_{x}}{\mu_{0}} \\
0 \\
vB_{x} - B_{y}u \\
wB_{x} - B_{z}u \\
e + p + \frac{B^{2}}{2\mu_{0}}u - \frac{\vec{B}\cdot\vec{v}}{\mu_{0}}B_{x}}
$$

$$
\vec{G} = 
\pmatrix{
\rho v \\ 
\rho u v - \frac{B_{x}B_{y}}{\mu_{0}} \\ 
\rho v^{2} - \frac{B_{y}^{2}}{\mu_{0}} + p + \frac{B^{2}}{2\mu_{0}} \\
\rho w v - \frac{B_{z}B_{y}}{\mu_{0}} \\
u B_{y} - B_{x}v \\
0 \\
wB_{y} - B_{z}v \\
e + p + \frac{B^{2}}{2\mu_{0}}v - \frac{\vec{B}\cdot\vec{v}}{\mu_{0}}B_{y}}
$$

$$
\vec{H} = 
\pmatrix{
\rho w \\ 
\rho u w - \frac{B_{x}B_{z}}{\mu_{0}} \\ 
\rho v w - \frac{B_{y}B_{z}}{\mu_{0}} \\
\rho w^{2} - \frac{B_{z}^{2}}{\mu_{0}} + p + \frac{B^{2}}{2\mu_{0}} \\
uB_{z} - B_{x}w \\
vB_{z} - B_{y}w \\
0 \\
e + p + \frac{B^{2}}{2\mu_{0}}w - \frac{\vec{B}\cdot\vec{v}}{\mu_{0}}B_{z}}
$$

From Jardin (2010), the general form is,

$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \vec{\nabla}\cdot{\rho\vec{u}} = 0
\\
\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} = \vec{\nabla}\times(\vec{u}\times\vec{B}) 
\\
\rho(\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t} + \vec{u}\cdot\vec{\nabla}\vec{u}) + \vec{\nabla}p = \vec{J}\times\vec{B} 
\\
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} + \vec{u}\cdot\vec{\nabla}p + \gamma p\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{u} = 0
$$

Comment: Could you write out the MHD equations in your post so more people will be able to answer?

Comment: Sorry, I understand, I will do so tomorrow. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that non-dimensionalization is important to implementing a numerical solver. I think that with a bit of care, simulators can be written in dimensional form, and in fact make a lot of things much easier.

Comment: Some degree of moving between dimensional and nondimensional forms is necessary for fluid simulations because so many of the relevent phenomena are governed by nondimensional parameters, but this is sometimes undone internally. It would help to know what exactly the issue is that supposedly necessitates nondimensionalization.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Would you mind expanding? The basis of my position is that really large, and really small numbers, like you would see expressed in many physical constants, are undesirable to work with in a computer.

Comment: @whpowell96 I added the system I'm solving. It's 8 equations broken down into their most atomic form, so it might be a little hard to parse. I'm working on writing down a more compact Navier-Stokes-like form

Comment: @whpowell96 I experienced an issue with nulls that I couldn't fix when I wrote this on a CPU. I just want to make sure that the mathematical basis is solid for the GPU implementation

Comment: In double precision, you can represent numbers up to $10^{308}$. That's large enough to express nearly everything in the universe if you use a reasonable set of base units. For example, for the earth, you can easily express everything in SI units. If you were to do cosmology, perhaps you should express lengths in light years, but you'd be on the safe side with this. So *expressing* large or small things is not a problem with today's floating point numbers. (I should say that that was *not* the case back in the days of single precision FP.)

Comment: The problem appears when building linear systems with blocks expressed in different physical units. That can be addressed by automatic scaling of variables before/after linear solves, but it does not require non-dimensionalization. Let me refer to this paper of mine here where we describe the design of a simulator for problems in Earth dynamics, which uses SI units: https://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/publications/2008-boussinesq.pdf See section 3.2.4

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth They're still undesirable to work with. Multiplying a large number amplifies roundoff error, and small numbers, for example the charge of an electron, are indistinguishable from machine precision.

Comment: unfortunately if you're planning to simulate conditions which match that of a unit'd system at some point you're going to have number scale mismatch somewhere because all the ugliness of differing scales comes back at least temporarily when you multiply against the normalization constants. This is somewhat unavoidable for explicit time stepping, and for implicit/matrix solve type systems you still have to account for this similar to how Wolfgang recommended.

Comment: Also multiplying a very large number by a small number in IEEE floating point has relatively little error by design. It's addition/subtraction which is usually the source of error, and normalization usually doesn't help here.

Comment: @helloworld922 Would you mind expanding? How does multiplication in this situation not amplify roundoff error? For example, if I multiply 1/3 by 10^23, but 1/3 is actually say 0.3333333333333000, etc. in memory, then the result would be off by many orders of magnitude.

Comment: but it's not off by orders of magnitude. You have an error in the 14th decimal point, and that will remain true in scientific notation after multiplying by 10^23. Multiplication and division across different magnitudes becomes addition/subtraction of the exponent (which is exact integers), with the same error incurred on the mantissa.

Comment: @Ashamandarei "Multiplying a large number amplifies roundoff error," -- No, that's just plain wrong. The relative error is entirely unaffected by the size of numbers, and we only ever care about relative error. "and small numbers, for example the charge of an electron, are indistinguishable from machine precision." That's also not true. The charge of an electron is approximately $10^{-19}$ Coulomb, which is not a problem at all in double precision where you can store numbers down to $10^{-308}$. It's not a problem because you're only ever going to add numbers of the same magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of physics you're interested in, but typically for MHD I tend to normalize the magnetic field energy to match the fluid energy:

\begin{gather}
e_0 = m_0 n_0 V_0^2\\
P_0 = e_0\\
B_0 = \sqrt{\mu_0 e_0}
\end{gather}
where $m_0$ is your reference particle mass (typically a proton).

This has some nice properties such as your Alfven velocity becomes
\begin{gather}
\frac{V_A}{V_0} = \sqrt{\frac{\tilde{B}^2}{\tilde{\rho}}}
\end{gather}
Similarly, you can analyze how magnetic field energy compares vs. other types of energy.